# PHP exec() not working on AppServ

Tags: php, r

I'm now facing the following problem. Please help me out.

I have two file in the same directory: **test.php** and **test.r**

**test.php**

```
<?php
  exec("Rscript test.r");
?>
```

**test.r**

```
d=c(1:10);
write.csv(d, file="test.csv", fileEncoding="utf-8");

q();
```

While I access the **test.php** via chrome, it gives no **test.csv**.

Although it works fine on *cmd* `Rscript test.r`, it does not work while executing **test.php**.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the executing option enabled in your PHP server and/or do you have writing permissions there?

Comment: You might also give a try to http://rapache.net

Comment: @PabloLemurr : I enabled all the permissions, but it still doesn't work:(

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check:

- File permissions. Set them to `0777` temporarily to see if it's working
- Maybe the `exec` function is blocked. Check `php.ini` (or `phpinfo()`) for [`disabled_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)
- Third options - is one you really always need to consider - an error in your script.

Happy debugging !

Answer (score 0):

`PHP/IIS` will need to read/execute permissions to the command you are trying to execute with your `exec()` function.

Go through [PHP documentation for exec() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) article.

Hope, It will resolve your problem.

Comment: I enabled all the permission, and other command instead of executing R work fine(eg. `$output = exec("ls -al"); echo $output;`)